# How to generate xml file from a textfile which has NESTED tags by using spark scala. Please give me some idea

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark

Below is the sample input file what I have:

```
johnson|26|M|6|BTECH|Acollege|a

RICHARD|27|M|7|BTECH|bcollege|a
```

Form this csv input I need to generate an xml file formatted as below:

```
<details>
    <employee_details>
        <personal_details>
             <name>Johnson</name>
             <age>26</age>   
             <gender>M</gender>
             <height>6</height>
        </personal_details>
        <education_details>
            <degree>BTECH</degree>
            <college_name>ACOLLEGE</college_name>
            <grade>a</grade>
        </education_details>
    </employee_details>
    <employee_details>
        <personal_details>
             <name>RICHARD</name>
             <age>27</age>   
             <gender>M</gender>
             <height>7</height>
        </personal_details>
        <education_details>
            <degree>BTECH</degree>
            <college_name>BCOLLEGE</college_name>
            <grade>a</grade>
        </education_details>
    </employee_details>
```

Please help me with this......

Comment: Like implies that it's different from what you are actually showing us. Add the code you've tried and the exact input and output you are expecting please.

Comment: I don't have any code.. I need to generate the xml output from an input textfile. I need output to be generated with nested tags like I have shown in above output file

Comment: Added the input and output files again for more clarification @s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [spark-xml](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml) to write the output in XML, Below is simple example for your case

Add dependency for Maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-xml_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>0.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Dependency for SBT

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.databricks/spark-xml
libraryDependencies += "com.databricks" %% "spark-xml" % "0.3.1"
```

Raw Data

```
  val df = Seq(
    ("johnson", "26", "M", "BTECH", "Acollege", "a"),
    ("RICHARD", "27", "M", "BTECH", "bcollege", "a")
  ).toDF("name", "age", "gender", "degree", "college_name", "grade")

  val resultDF = df.withColumn("personal_details", struct("name", "age", "gender"))
    .withColumn("education_details", struct("degree", "college_name", "grade"))
    .select("personal_details.*", "education_details.*")


  resultDF.write
    .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
    .option("rootTag", "details")
    .option("rowTag", "employee_details")
    .save("outputtttttt/test.xml")
```

Output:

```
<details>
    <employee_details>
        <personal_details>
            <name>johnson</name>
            <age>26</age>
            <gender>M</gender>
        </personal_details>
        <education_details>
            <degree>BTECH</degree>
            <college_name>Acollege</college_name>
            <grade>a</grade>
        </education_details>
    </employee_details>
    <employee_details>
        <personal_details>
            <name>RICHARD</name>
            <age>27</age>
            <gender>M</gender>
        </personal_details>
        <education_details>
            <degree>BTECH</degree>
            <college_name>bcollege</college_name>
            <grade>a</grade>
        </education_details>
    </employee_details>
</details>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: which spark version you are using. this code is not giving me exact result.below are my dependices. I am using spark 1.6
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-xml_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.0</version>
</dependency>

Comment: I am using spark 2.1.0, check the different dependency for spark 1.6

Comment: I am using 0.2.0 version of spark_xml and 1.6 in spark version...... I think in this version it is not possible i guess....... Need some help in this version

Comment: any idea how to acheive this in spark 1.6

Comment: you can check the documentation here for spark 1.6 https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml/tree/branch-0.3
I have tested only with spark 2.x

Comment: I am able to generate the required output. only thing to change is, while selecting a columns from a dataframe we need to select the column as struct like this "val resultDF_1 = resultDF.select(struct($"name",$"age",$"gender").alias("s3:personal_details"),struct($"degree",$"college_name",$"grade").alias("s3:education_details"))". Thanks to @Shankar Koirala for giving me idea

Comment: I am very glad that helped you :)